# Empty zip returned while generating zip of images with JSZip

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, zip, jszip

I am using JSZip and trying to create a zip of Images (given URL's of images). Initially I was trying with the base64 conversion (`canvas.toDataURL`) but that is generating some corrupt images inside zip. So that, later I switched to blob based approach. Now I am creating canvas from img and then convert it to blob to zip it.  Now since `canvas.toBlob` method is running asynchronously, my end zip files returns to be empty (with an empty images folder in it). This might be the reason i guessed. I might be wrong.

```
$("#download-images-small").on("click", function(){
    var links = []
    // get the list of images on page
    var selections = $('.checkbox:checked').parent('label').siblings("img")
    var zip = new JSZip();
    zip.folder("images");
    var img = zip.folder("images");

    for (var i = selections.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        filename = $(selections[i]).attr('title') + "." + $(selections[i]).data('type')
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.width = selections[i].width;
        canvas.height = selections[i].height;
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.drawImage(selections[i], 0, 0);
        canvas.toBlob(function (blob) {
           zip.file(filename, blob);
        });
    }

    zip.generateAsync({type:"blob"}).then(function(content) {
      saveAs(content, "compressed.zip");
    });
});
```

Please help me with a better approach if possible. Thanks.

Comment: The `canvas.toBlob` function contains a callback that should be take a long time, so when the `generateAsync` function is executed then `toBlob` the function is not finished. You must be call `generateAsync` using setTimeout after of `for` cycle.

Comment: I have tried that. putting 5 sec in setTimeOut. But only single image received in zip, while i had a list of 100.

Comment: use `async` and `await` keyword because everything is called async